# Adding and rotating labels using Coretext (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am overriding `draw` and would like to add some labels.  CoreText is new to me and I can't find examples to get a grasp on it.

I am struggling in particular with:

- drawing the "label" at its proper (x,y) position (centered at *x* when horizontal, right-justified when rotated)
- how to rotate the label 90° counterclockwise (-CGFloat.pi / 2),
- determining the height and width (when horizontal, the width is the length of string and the height is the height of a single character; when vertical the height is the length of the string, and the width is the height of a single character.  I will need the y-value of the bottom of the longest label).

A couple of notes for context:

Ultimately, the goal is to display some labels across a graph so that they do not overlap.  If they would overlap horizontally, I rotate them 90°.

Because I began using CAShapeLayer, my label info (text and location) is already in an array of `UILabel`s.  (Don't know if this is a good way to do this or not...  maybe use a tuple to store (*x*, *y*, *text*) instead?)

Here is what I have so far:

```
func displayLabels(labelArray: [UILabel], rotate: Bool) {
    
    let font = fontLabels
    
    // rotate 90° counterclockwise if specified
    let rotationAngle = rotate ? -CGFloat.pi / 2 : 0 
    
    for i in 0 ..< labelArray.count {
        let label = labelArray[i]
        
        // this no longer works correctly:
        // x-value should be center of label, not top left if not rotated
        // y-value should be center of label, not top left if rotated
        var x = label.frame.origin.x
        let y = label.frame.origin.y            
        x -= rotate ? label.bounds.midY : label.bounds.midX

        
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
        
        let attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
        
        let string = label.text

        //what are the height and width?  put some temp numbers in here to test...
        string!.draw(with: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 10, height: 50), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attrs, context: nil)
                                
    }
}
```